# Change font size of last 2 characters in combobox list aswell as the text selected

Tags: excel

I have a combo box in excel.
I want the font of the last 2 characters for each item in the list to be font size 1.
Once the user selects an option and it is diosplayed in the cell, I want the font size of the last 2 characters to be font size 1.

FYI The reason I want this is the value they select has a score e.g optionone-5 so I need the text -5 to have font size one. I use this in a calculation. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: What kind of combo_box are you referring to.

Comment: As far as I know, combobox text must be all same size and font. Not sure if this can be achieved. What kind of combobox are you using?